# Testing an angular service that uses another service that uses $http

Tags: angularjs, http, mocking, jasmine, promise

I've got two angular services that I have written.

One called "searchAPI" which essentially accepts user input, forms elastic search queries, and then fires them off via an $http.get call.

```
//searchAPI

service = {
    executeSearch: function(input, resultsPerPage, pageNumber){
        request = // some well tested logic that I know works to create a query string
        return $http.get(request);
    }
}
```

And another called typeAhead, which uses my searchAPI to grab a list of typeAhead results.

```
//typeAhead

service = {

    typeAheadContent: [],

    buildTypeAheadContent: function(input){
        return searchAPI.executeSearch(input, 10, 1).then(function(res){
            for(var i = 0; i < res.length; i++){
                service.typeAheadContent.push(res[i]);
            }
        });
    },  

    getTypeAheadResults: function(input){
        return service.buildTypeAheadContent(input).then(function(){
            return service.typeAheadContent;
        });     
    }
};
```

A few things here.

1) I'm still getting the hang of angular, so I don't know if my promise setup is completely up to par or not. I have other uses for the searchAPI request building functionality besides just in my typeahead, which is why I wanted to make the request builder/firer into its own separate thing.

2) I need help testing this typeAhead service. For the unit tests, how would I ensure that the searchAPI doesn't actually go to my backend, but instead returns some mock data or mock promise or something? Something like this would be ideal, if I could do it.

```
searchAPI.executeSearch = function(){
    return [
        'item1',
        'item2',
        'item3'
    ]
}
```

I tried doing something like this in my jasmine tests, but by mocking it in this way, I am not invoking a promise, just setting a return value.

Could someone help me get started with my setup and mocking out some promises?

////EDIT////

Here is my before each function in my jasmine test.

```
var searchAPI, typeAhead;
beforeEach(inject($rootScope, $injector, $q)
{
    typeAhead = $injector.get('typeAhead');
    searchAPI = $injector.get('searchAPI');
    searchAPI.executeSearch = function(input, resultsPerPage, pageNumber){

        // this is being alerted just fine
        alert("Inside mock");
        return $q.when([
            'item1', 'item2', 'item3'
        ]);
    }
    $rootScope.$digest();
}));

it('should construct typeahead stuff', function(){

    searchAPI.executeSearch("hello", 10, 1).then(function(res){

        //this is not being alerted
        alert(res);
    });
    typeAhead.buildTypeAheadContent("test");
});
```

So I included a few things to help debug. The line of code that alerts "Inside Mock" is indeed being alerted, so I know my mock thing that I assigned to executeSearch is being set up properly. However, the code inside the .then block is not being alerted, so my promise must not be resolved or something...

Answer (score 1):

Your usage of promises sounds just fine and up to par with what it's supposed to look like. That's good.

As for your problem - I'd probably mock it to reflect the original API - to mock promises with a static value - you can use `$q.when`:

```
searchAPI.executeSearch = function(){
    return $q.when([
        'item1',
        'item2',
        'item3'
    ]);
};
```

`$q.when` converts a foreign (non Angular) promise or a simple value to an Angular promise - in this case your array.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I'll try this out after lunch and see if it does what I need, then you get your acceptance :)

Comment: This is still not quite what I want unfortunately.. 

In my test, I tried 

searchAPI.executeSearch().then(function(res){alert(res);});

and nothing was alerted.

Comment: Try adding a `$rootScope.digest()` after it assuming you're not using 1.3

Comment: I don't know if I am or not, but I tried adding a $rootScope.digest() after setting searchAPI.executeSearch() and I got the error message "$rootScope.digest is not a function"

Comment: ok $rootScope.$digest fixed ^ this issue, but I still am not seeing anything alerted when I try and do a "searchAPI.executeSearch().then(function(res){alert(res);});"

Comment: Yeah, it's $digest - also, you need to get a reference to Angular's rootScope

Comment: I'm passing it in via my beforeEach in the test, I'll edit my original post to show an example.

Comment: Alright it is posted, the code I added was too long to really show what I wanted to show. If you take a look, you see that I am passing in $rootScope through beforeEach